# Control process concurrency in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, multiprocess

I have programmed a simple app that every X minutes checks if an image has changed in several websites and downloads it. It's very simple: downloads image header, make some CRC checks, downloads the file, stores in a MySQL database some data about each image and process next item...

This process takes about 1 minute to complete.

The problem is I have noticed that while the server is executing this process I cannot access to any page in the website, even those that don't require MySQL.

I don't know why it is happening and I have no clue about how to fix it. Perhaps a more advanced PHP programmer can help me.

Comment: what server is it?  sounds like your code is hooked to the inner thread

Comment: The process is a PHP script called via the web ? or is it a cron task ?

Comment: It's a PHP script called via the web, but it is installed in local environment (not production yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of session files locks
Try to unset sessions cookie and load page, if I right - page is loaded

It would be correct to remove execute this script from web, but if this is necessary, use [session_write_close()](http://ru.php.net/session_write_close) function to close session and unlock session file